# Converting multiple row values to field values based on similar FID using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have a polyline layer containing information that I have attempted to spatial join onto a buffer polygon.  The problem is that I now have multiple rows that have the same FID, and differing values in the field I want to extract information from.  What I need to do is take all the values contained in the target field, and preserve them in just one row using the original FID as the preserving value.  Please see my attached images for clarification.

I do not know Python, so will need to do this with standard geoprocessing tool.

[image: Image 1 showing the polygons and lines]

[image: Image 2 showing the display in a table. I want to preserve all feed ID values under just one row with the FID.]

Comment: In the Spatial Join field map you can define the Merge Rule as Join. This will concatenate multiple joined values into a single field.

Comment: Thank you, klewis.  Can you provide some more clarification or an image of where you chance the rule in the field map?

Comment: you can right-click a field, select Properties. You should see Merge rule: and Delimiter: options to define. The delimiter could be a comma or other character that will be placed after each Joined value.